# Installing kubernetes on less ram

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to install kubernetes by kubeadm init command on system has RAM less than 1GB ?I have tried to install but it failed in kubeadm init command.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [installation steps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubeadm/#before-you-begin) to be taken before you begin, you need to have:

- linux compatible system for master and nodes
- 2GB or more RAM per machine
- network connectivity
- swap disabled on every node

But going back to your question, It may be possible to run the installation process, but the further usability is not possible. This configuration will be not stable.

Comment: my error log of kubelet is :05:05:49.825163     reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:452: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://xxx.xxx.x.xx:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.1.17:6443: getsockopt: connection refused